# Ordering of Bool types (i.e. True > False) - Why?

Tags: haskell

Can someone please explain the following output?

```
Prelude> compare True False
GT
it :: Ordering
Prelude> compare False True
LT
it :: Ordering
```

Why are `Bool` type values ordered in Haskell - especially, since we can demonstrate that values of True and False are not exactly 1 and 0 (unlike many other languages)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how the derived instance of `Ord` works:

```
data D = A | B | C deriving Ord
```

Given that datatype, we get `C > B > A`. Bool is defined as `False | True`, and it kind of makes sense when you look at other examples such as:

- `Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`
- `Either a b = Left a | Right b`

In each of the case having "some" ("truthy") value is greater than having no values at all (or having "left" or "bad" or "falsy" value).

Comment: That was a cool way of putting it. But i don't get the second example. Perhaps you can elaborate more (on why Right b > Left a)?

Comment: @archilius it's connected to the `Monad` instance for `Either`. Basically `Left` means "failure" and `Right` means "success".

Answer (score 5):

While `Bool` is not `Int`, it can be converted to the `0,1` fragment of `Int` since it is an `Enum` type.

```
fromEnum False = 0
fromEnum True  = 1
```

Now, the `Enum` could have been different, reversing `0` and `1`, but that would probably be surprising to most programmers thinking about bits.

Since it has an `Enum` type, everything else being equal, it's better to define an `Ord` instance which follows the same order, satisfying

```
compare x y = compare (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y)
```

In fact, each instance generated from `deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)` follows such property.

On a more theoretical note, logicians tend to order propositions from the strongest to the weakest (forming a lattice). In this structure, `False` (as a proposition) is the bottom, i.e. the least element, while `True` is the top. While this is only a convention (theory would be just as nice if we picked the opposite ordering), it's a good thing to be consistent.

Minor downside: the implication boolean connective is actually `p <= q`  expressing that `p` implies `q`, instead of the converse as the "arrow" seems to indicate.

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer your question with a question: Why is there an `Ord` instance for `()`?

Unlike `Bool`, `()` has only one possible value: `()`. So why the hell would you ever want to compare it? There is only one value possible!

Basically, it's useful if all or most of the standard basic types have instances for common classes. It makes it easier to derive instances for your own types. If `Foo` doesn't have an `Ord` instance, and your new type has a single `Foo` field, then you can't auto-derive an `Ord` instance.

You might, for example, have some kind of tree type where we can attach several items of information to the leaves. Something like `Tree x y z`. And you might want to have an `Eq` instance to compare trees. It would be annoying if `Tree () Int String` didn't have an `Eq` instance just because `()` doesn't. So that's why `()` has `Eq` (and `Ord` and a few others).

Similar remarks apply to `Bool`. It might not sound particularly *useful* to compare two bool values, but it would be irritating if your `Ord` instance vanishes as soon as you put a bool in there.

(One other complicating factor is that sometimes we want `Ord` because there's a logically meaningful ordering for things, and sometimes we just want *some* arbitrary order, typically so we can use something as a key for `Data.Map` or similar. Arguably there ought to be two separate classes for that… but there isn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it comes from math. In set theory or category theory boolean functions are usually thought of as classifiers of subsets/subobjects. In plain terms, function `f :: a -> Bool` is identified with `filter f :: [a] -> [a]`. So, if we change one value from `False` to `True`, the resulting filtered list (subset, subobject, whatever) is going to have more elements. Therefore, `True` is considered "bigger" than `False`.